# Regex to limit the number of spaces in a text string

Tags: regex, spaces

I am trying to establish the following but I am unable to. I need to allow no spaces at all or a maximum of 2 white spaces within my text string.
Following is my regex:

```
/^([^\s]*\s[^\s]*){0,2}$/
```

The above one is partially working fine i.e. allowing 1 to max 2 spaces within my text however, its failing when there are NO SPACES at all in my text although I have defined 0 to 2.

Any help?

Comment: Do you want to limit to a _total_ of two or less spaces, or do you want to only allow two or less whitespaces together?

Comment: It should be written like `^(?:\S*\s){0,2}\S*$` or `^\S*(?:\s\S*){0,2}$`. Also, could you please explain where you are using the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^([^\s]*[\s]?[^\s]*){0,2}$
```

`[^\s]*` matches a space zero or one times.

Comment: You may use `\S` instead of `[^\s]`, the former which is much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to allow more than two continuous spaces, then use a negative lookahead assertion:

```
/^(?!.*[ ]{3,}).*$/
```

If you want to limit to a total of two or fewer spaces, then use:

```
/^\S*\s?\S*\s?\S*$/
```

Comment: the first regex is missing a `)`?